# C# abstract classes inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

hej guys,

I am trying to solve this homework. I have reached a dead end and I am looking for someone who could help with this issue.

This is the task I am trying to solve:

> Work 2: An abstract class is not a complete class, it misses some
>   parts, and you cannot create     objects from it. The programmer who
>   writes the derived classes must fill in the missing    parts. Consider
>   an abstract class Vehicle. Derive two hierarchies from this class as
>   it  is shown below: Now, write 4 classes, see the yellow rectangle.
>   Start from the abstract  base class Vehicle -> Vehicle with 4 wheels
>   -> Sport Cars and stop at the derived class          Rally, which is the most specific class. The class Vehicle contains a field which
>   holds   the vehicle name and an abstract method void Display().
>
> Implement this function in the derived classes, so that the function
>   returns  information about the vehicle, e.g. the motor power and other
>   necessary properties. The  last derived class has private fields to
>   hold the motor power, the car weight, the car  acceleration, the
>   highest speed and a function that computes the specific power (power 
>   / weight). The function Display returns a text string with all this
>   information. Test  your work in a Console application that uses
>   objects of the type of the classes Sport  car and Rally.

Class Vehicle:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace A_work_2
{
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public string vehicleName;
    public abstract void Display();

}
}
```

Class Vehicle4Wheels:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace A_work_2
{
public class Vehicle4Wheels : Vehicle
{
    public override void Display() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Car with four wheels.");
    }
}
}
```

Class SportCar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace A_work_2
{
public class SportCar : Vehicle4Wheels {
    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sport version of the car.");
    }
}
}
```

Class Rally:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace A_work_2
{
public class Rally : SportCar
{
private double motorPower = 408;
private double carWeight = 2380;
private double carAcceleration = 4.7;
private double highestSpeed = 250;

public double SpecificPower()
{
    double specificPower = motorPower / carWeight;
    return specificPower;
}

public override void Display()
{

   Console.WriteLine("The acceleration is: {0}.\nThe highest speed is {1} km/h.", carAcceleration, highestSpeed);
   Console.WriteLine("Specific power is {0}", SpecificPower());


}
}
}
```

I am not sure if I understand the task clearly and with the code I have so far, I dont know if I am on the right way to make it happen. I dont understand abstract classes and inhertiance very much.

Thank you for your help!

V.

EDIT: My question is: How can I change the code I have written to fulfill the task I have been given? Because I am not sure how to be general while writing the code. When I add car attribute to the Vehicle4Wheels class like:

```
private double carWeight;
```

How can I then approach this attribute in later derived classes?

Comment: Please format your question well

Comment: I think you have answered what needs to be done. The main point is seems is to populate the Display function to return data related to the class using any additional properties available - which you have done. In all honesty, the assignment brief is not very clear about what you are supposed to do - a lot of space for misunderstanding

Comment: So with out even reading/understanding the concepts, you have started to work on it. Better stop your work and read the articles about it. Google up, youll get alot of articles.

Comment: what is this, homeworkoverflow?

Comment: You don't really seem to have asked anything here. Your code all looks fine to me at a glance and seems to satisfy your requirements but I may be missing something. Please be more precise with your question or you will find it will get closed because it is too vague and people cant' work out what you are asking.

Comment: @The_Butcher Hey, thanks for answering. If I don't know something I try to find out, and when I don't know I ask someone. Since you don't like that I ask for help with my homework, why do you bother reading it?

Comment: @Vojtech - To tell you that I don't like it?? :D

Comment: @Vojtech You mentioned you dont understand abstract classes and inheritance much, I strongly suggest you get this book http://www.amazon.co.uk/Illustrated-2010-Experts-Voice-NET/dp/143023282X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1318932456&sr=8-1 I used it myself at uni, and even use it now to brush up on some of the concepts

Comment: @Vojtech: I still don't get what the question is. The requirements say you have to implement the Display() function in derived classes which you seem to have done. "I want to match the spec" is better butstill not a well phrased question. A real question would be something like "I don't know how to write a console app to test this as it tells me to". That is the only bit of spec that I can see that doesn't look, at a glance, to be satisfied...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure if I understand the task clearly and with the code I have so far, I dont know if I am on the right way to make it happen

So, lets review what you've got so far...

> When I add car attribute to the Vehicle4Wheels class like:
>   private double carWeight;
>   How can I then approach this attribute in later derived classes?

Your homework assignment didn't tell you to worry about that.

> "The last derived class has private fields to hold the motor power, the car weight, the car acceleration, the highest speed and a function that computes the specific power (power / weight)"

You've implemented this pretty well already.  The part you are missing is this:

> "Test your work in a Console application that uses objects of the type of the classes Sport car and Rally."

Once you've implemented this, you'll understand the point of all the code you've written.

To make it interesting, and so you get the point of the exercise, make sure your console app does something like this:

```
Vehicle sportCar = new SportCar();
sportCar.Display();

Vehicle rally = new Rally();
rally.Display();
```

Notice I didn't say `Rally rally = new Rally();`

Also notice that `Vehicle something = new SportsCar();` works.  Try adding a line: `Vehicle something = new Vehicle();` - It won't compile.

This all will demonstrate some of the most important parts of inheritance and (abstract) base types:

- You can interact with a base type and get derived behavior
- You can't create instances of abstract types directly, but you can still use those types in your code

Try this all and see what happens.

Comment: hej, thank you for your answer. So if I understand it correctly, the Display method I have made in Vehicle Class is used by all the derived classes to show the information in their overriden Display classes, correct?

Comment: @Vojtech: Almost, yes.  That statement would be correct if you said "overridden Display methods" instead of "overridden Display classes".  A class *is* something and a method *does* something, so you can't interchange the terms freely...

Comment: yes, sorry my bad. I know I meant methods. Dont know why I have written classes. Too much of programming today I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

Some of those values (highestSpeed, carWeight and so on) could apply to *any* "Vehicle with 4 wheels" (or even "vehicle"), so you can define properties for those values at *that* level.

In the constructor (of the derived class) you can then provide values for those properties.

The Display method can then read those properties, so you don't even have to override that method on higher levels.

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx, about constructors and how you can call the constructor of a base class from the constructor of a derived class.

Comment: I would say motorPower would only apply to a "motor vehicle"... 4 wheels does not mean motor vehicle - I am not saying your answer is wrong, more that the assignment spec is a bit poor

Comment: @musefan - changed to 'highestSpeed' :-)

Comment: @Vojtech: You could do all this, and in a real app it would be a good idea.  But this isn't what the assignment says to do, so I wouldn't turn it in like this.